# Как затруднить дизассемблирование приложения?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, обфускация

Есть проект, который будет компилироваться при помощи MSVC, в будущем возможно и другими компиляторами. Какие существуют приложения для усложнения дизассемблирования результата моего труда? Я предпочитаю open source приложения.

Comment: Запускать на сервере, к которому нет доступа у тех кто будет (может) дизассемблировать. Остальное все имеет околонулевую эффективность.

Comment: Open-source решение по сокрытию исходников? Хм, что-то в этом есть.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще дизассемблер всегда будет выполнен, если программа исполнима, так как между ассемблером и машинными кодами взаимно однозначное соответствие. То есть именно "усложнить дизассемблирование" не получится - оно будет выполнено. Вот разобрать ехешник на составные усложнить можно - смотри в сторону шифрования исполняемого кода и восстановление его в сегмент с разрешением исполнения впоследствии. Всё же отладчик нельзя будет обойти, так как он работает уже с развернутым в памяти работающим кодом.

Answer (score 0):

VMProtect, Armadillo и прочие коммерческие пакеры вам в помощь. Opensource-решений такого класса не существует.